# editing android build.prop with a script

Tags: android, shell, scripting

I'm trying to create a script to modify the build.prop file 'automatically'. 
I want the script to check for entries I define and:
1. If they do not exist add them
2. If they do exist, check the value, and if it does not match what I've define modify it.

I have created a script.
It runs but outputs nothing, not changing the build.prop

I've attached the script. Is it correct?

```
#!/system/bin/sh 

# Definitions 
file=/system/build.prop 
tmpf=/system.buildprop.bak
line_list="wifi.supplicant_scan_interval=120 ro.sf.lcd_density=480" 

# Function to get args as needed for loop
getargs() {

par=$1
line=`echo $par |cut -d"=" -f1`
arg=`echo $par |cut -d"=" -f2`
} 

# Loop to make all changes in line_list 
for x in $line_lst; do 

# Get all needed arguments 
getargs $x 

# Write this change to a tmp file to check on it
oldarg=`grep $line $file |cut -d"=" -f2`
sed "s/$line=.*/$line=${arg}/g" $file > $tmpf

# Check if the change was made
chknewarg=`grep $line $tmpf |cut -d"=" -f2`
if [ "$chknewarg" = "$arg" ]; then
cp $tmpf $file
if [ -f $tmpf ]; then
rm $tmpf
fi
echo "File edited"
else
if [ -f $tmpf ]; then
rm $tmpf
fi
echo "Expected $arg, got $chknewarg instead"
exit 1
fi
# If it doesn't exist at all append it to the file
chkexists=`grep -c $line $file`
if [ $chkexists -eq 0 ]; then
echo "$x" >> $file
fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Run the script with `sh -x` to debug it more easily. Also, indenting your code a little wouldn't hurt, it would certainly make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bit more playing and fundamentally changes the script.

```
#/system/bin/sh

 mount -o remount,rw /system

FILE=/system/build.prop
TMPFILE=$FILE.tmp

line1=wifi.supplicant_scan_interval
line2=ro.sf.lcd_density
line3=ro.media.enc.jpeg.quality

line1Arg=120
line2Arg=390
line3Arg=100

lineNum=

prop=$line1     
arg=$line1Arg   
if grep -Fq $prop $FILE ; then  
lineNum=`sed -n "/${prop}/=" $FILE`   
echo $lineNum
sed -i "${lineNum} c${prop}=${arg}" $FILE   
else
echo "$prop does not exist in build.prop"   
echo "appending to end of build.prop"
echo $prop=$arg >> $FILE
fi

prop=$line2     
arg=$line2Arg     
if grep -Fq $prop $FILE ; then  
lineNum=`sed -n "/${prop}/=" $FILE`    
echo $lineNum
sed -i "${lineNum} c${prop}=${arg}" $FILE    
else
echo "$prop does not exist in build.prop"   
echo "appending to end of build.prop"
echo $prop=$arg >> $FILE
fi

prop=$line3     
arg=$line3Arg     
if grep -Fq $prop $FILE ; then  
lineNum=`sed -n "/${prop}/=" $FILE`    
echo $lineNum
sed -i "${lineNum} c${prop}=${arg}" $FILE    
else
echo "$prop does not exist in build.prop"   
echo "appending to end of build.prop"
echo $prop=$arg >> $FILE
fi

mount -o remount,r /system
```

However I get a 'mount: invalid argument' error?

Also, how would a loop over the line and lineArg variables to compete the actions?

Comment: The `'mount: invalid argument` is because the read-only remount should be `mount -o remount,ro /system`.